# Display One Table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am creating a plugin for my wordpress site.  I have made tables for each year & want to display ONLY for the current year, and it be automaticly updated to the new year & new table each year.  Would also like the previous years to be able to be viewed at search.  Please tell me How can I do this?  I included a sample of my basic html 2017 table for an example.

```html
<table class="info">
      <tr style="font-size:15px"><th colspan="4">2017</th></tr>
      <tr style="font-size:13px">
      <th>Row 1</th>
      <th>Row 2</th>
      <th>Row 3</th>
      <th>Row 4</th>
      </tr><tr>
         <td>info</td><td>info</td><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>   </tr>
         </tr></table>
```

Comment: what did you try so far? this is just the html, did you write any code so far?

Comment: I have the tables & css.  I do not know how to call them by year.  Right now they are listed consecutively one after the other in the same file since they are each only about 7-15 rows.  I am not sure how to proceed.  Not made a plugin before, so I am a bit lost.